# How to check if a container only has a specific element?

Tags: c++

I apologize if the wording is completely off. I am very very new to C++ syntax. For background, I have an object named system that holds elements called actions. Like so below:

```
for (event::System system : Ev->getSys())
{
    for (event::Action actions : system.actions)
    {
        switch (thing)
```

I was wondering if there is a way to check if system (in the first for loop) has the same element within it. For example,

If it has only RUN (or RUN, RUN, RUN...etc), then execute a specific set of code. Or if it has different types like RUN, STOP, WALK, then it can proceed. I know it will be an if/else statement but I can't think of how to build the condition for it.

Comment: You can use `std::all_of` to check if the first element of the container is the same as all of the others.

Comment: Sure can. I'd write a function like `is_all_run` and then do `if (is_all_run(system.actions)) {do the stuff if it's all RUN} else {do the stuff if it's not all RUN}`. As Nathan says it's in the standard library, but you might find it easier to understand if you write your own function.